# Navigating across multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, navigation

I'm fairly new to iOS development. I'm working on an App that segues to multiple table view controllers. When my application launches, it loads view controller A. I then click on a row in View Controller A to segue to view controller B. The navigation button (back button) in View Controller B shows the title of View Controller A. I then click on a row in View Controller B which will segue to View Controller C. When I click a row in View Controller C, I segue back to View Controller B. My problem is that when I segue from View Controller C to View Controller B, the navigation button (back button) on View Controller B shows the title of View Controller C. I would like it to still show the title of View Controller A. Can anyone help on how this can be done? Sample code will be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use a segue to go from C to B, then you need to use an unwind segue. This has the advantage over using popViewControllerAnimated: in that you can use prepareForSegue to send information back to view controller B just like you would for a forward segue.

Comment: Thanks rdelmar...this works great. For some reason, the tableview in B does not refresh with the data that was selected in C. Doing the NSLog on B, I can see that the data selected in C was correctly passed to B but the table view cells in B dont refresh with selected data. I tried - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
} but it only refreshes the first row and not the rest of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `popViewControllerAnimated` function. Have a look here : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popViewControllerAnimated:

I think its pretty simple to use so I hope you will not need sample code.